# I'm stuck after "Installation Complete" message

Tags: 16.04

I've pressed "Restart Now" and my laptop froze. My power button doesn't work either and there is no way to remove the battery. My laptop is an HP pavilion 15-cb091nd

Comment: Have you tried pressing the power button for ~10 seconds?

Comment: @danzel I've hold it for a minute, with no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you just quickly pressed the power button, since you must have had a way to turn the laptop on in the first place. Therefore use the following in order of precedence:

1. Try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>**B**</kbd>. This will get the laptop to **B**oot.
   On some laptops, you may need to press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to  get <kbd>SysRq</kbd> to work. 
   On some laptops there is no <kbd>SysRq</kbd>, use <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> instead.
2. You should be able to simply hold down the power button for at least 10 seconds.
3. If all else fails, just let the battery run dry. In this case, you probably have more to worry about than the system not restarting, and I'd suggest getting the power button checked out whether or not it has a hardware error.

Comment: what is the *SysRq* key?

Comment: The laptop is only 3 months old and worked perfectly with Windows 10. The power button also worked correctly. I've tried to dual boot Ubuntu and got this. I also don't have a SysRq key.

Comment: @damadam it's typically found with the same key as the print screen key. See here for more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I had to hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrnSc</kbd> and pressed <kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. It shuts down my laptop.

Comment: That's the same answer as the existing one.  B = Boot

Comment: @Fabby Yes, the answer didn't have the PrtSc before, but now that it does, I marked it as correct.

Comment: favour returned, question upvoted...  You can always press the [delete] button under your answer... (not *telling* you, just suggesting...)